# How can i apply CRT??

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

I'm solving a problem to show that $SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z}) \longrightarrow SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z}/N \mathbb{Z})$ is a surjective group homomorphism.
I realized that I just had to show that:
If $(\overline{a}. \overline{b})=\mathbb{Z}/N \mathbb{Z}$, then there exist an integer $n$ such that $(a,b+nN)=\mathbb{Z}.$
How can i apply CRT to show this? I will appreciate it if you could give me a detail. Thank you :)

Comment: I don't think Critical Race Theory can help here.